# Certain utf-8 characters break subject lines in mutt

Tags: mutt

Certain UTF-8 symbols break subject lines. I see this problem in konsole (ubuntu) and termux (android) terminals. Bad subject line:

```
Subject: =?utf-8?B?4pqh77iP0JDQutGG0LjRjyDQt9Cw0LLQtdGA0YjQsNC10YLRgdGPISA=?=
 =?utf-8?B?0KPRgdC/0LXQudGC0LUg0LfQsNCx0YDQsNGC0Ywg0J7QkdCYINGA0YPQsdC7?=
 =?utf-8?B?0Lg=?=
```

If I place cursor on that line then the termanal looks like this:

[image: broken mutt 1]

And if I walk down and up a bit then it duplicates next line, pulling text:

[image: broken mutt 2]

And everything below that line is messed up. Any ideas how to filter out these characters? Nowadays more and more people use these "fancy" things in subjects, breaking message list.

This problem is common for all versions of mutt and neomutt, old and new.